# Combinatorial equivalence of Minkowski Sum of two Polytope

Tags: convex-geometry, polytopes

On Page 8 (or Page 250 as mentioned in the article) of [BASIC PROPERTIES OF CONVEX POLYTOPES](https://page.math.tu-berlin.de/%7Ehenk/preprints/henk%20richter-gebert%20ziegler&basic%20properties%20of%20convex%20polytopes.pdf), under the definition of Minkowski sum it is given that $P+\lambda P'$ is combinatorially equivalent for all $\lambda>0.$

Two polytopes are combinatorially equivalent if their face lattices are the same. So, for example, I was trying to prove that $P+P'$ and $P+2P'$ are combinatorially equivalent by showing that there is inclusion-preserving one-to-one correspondence $\phi$ between their faces. If $F$ is a face of $P+P'$ then $F=F_1+F_2$ for some $F_1\in P$ and $F_2\in P'$. But I am unsure what $\phi(F)$ would be in this case as Minkowski sum of two faces need not be a face.

Any hint or direction?

Comment: Does chapter 3 of [this thesis](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=65bcdeee4cc525f619047e629bf7a8a5ad676fdb) help?

Comment: Thank you, Rob. I was unaware of the concept of normal fans, but I eventually figured out the answer.